# Logo and image layout changes aren't reflected on mobile

Tags: wordpress, mobile-website, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-theme-astra

I'm making a website using starter template in Astra theme through Spectra, desktop version seems good but when checking the website on mobile it only shows the logo which initially came with starter template instead of my logo which I've used on customising the template. Moreover, even any changes in the image layouts aren't reflected in mobile site.

I'm new to wordpress and might be missing something important to configure, the plugin I'm using is LiteSpeed Cache and tried purging all the cache but it doesn't fix the mobile version of my website. Not sure if it's because of starter template or Astra theme but I thought it's quite popular worldwide tested theme so, might be something else